# How to query and display a common section of text across a category?

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

We have SMW installed for our internal wiki at work. There is a category called "X" which has "A", "B" and "C" pages with a section in each of those pages called "Contact".

Question: How do I write a query that displays this contact section from each of the pages that belong to "X" category?

**I've already..**

I read up [Help:Selecting pages](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Selecting_pages) and was able to list all pages under X category from Special:Ask page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm assuming it's too many pages to manually go in to and add semantic properties corresponding to the content in the "Contact" section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to define a property of type text - you can do that with help of the page Special:CreateProperty.

Then in each page of category "X" you need to assign the "contact" text to that property - like this:

```
[[YourPropertyName::contact text]]
```

Then on the page where you want to output all the contact text you can do something like

```
{{#ask:[[YourPropertyName::+]]}}
```